# How to concatenate parameter with colons in macro?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I want to write a macro that generates a vector with a name that consists of the name + type. So, `GEN_NAME_TYPE_MEMBER(int, Id)` should generate `vector<int> vec_Id_int`. `GEN_NAME_TYPE_MEMBER(std::string, FName)` should generate `vector<int> vec_Id_string`.

The following macro almost does it, but it fails when there is colons

```
#define GEN_NAME_TYPE_MEMBER(Name, Type)
    std::vector<Type> vec_##Name_##Type;
```

**INITIAL SOLUTION**

move the `Type` to the beginning of the name

```
 #define GEN_NAME_TYPE_MEMBER(Name, Type)
        std::vector<Type> Type##_##Name_vec;
```

Is there a way to put at the end of the name?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do that, in our code we put a `using` declaration before calling the macro with only the actual name.

Comment: Don't use macros if *at all* possible.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, if you have a different solution without macros, I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: How about just writing out the vector declarations where you need them?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, this is part of a bigger task that I'm working on. I need to generate classes that have such vectors inside

Comment: @riv, can you give an example what you mean?

Comment: It might seem like a time-saver and good idea at the moment, but in the long run macros will just make your code harder to read, understand and most importantly harder to maintain.

Comment: Macros can put sequences of tokens together, but they can't take them apart. There is no mechanism to extract `string` from `std :: string`

Comment: @theateist, Perhaps there's an easier way to do what you want to do. If the idea is to dynamically create members of a class (for whatever reason) then you might consider putting all that stuff in `std::map` that can accept different types (i.e your map will hold member names as keys and map entries will use an additional class that will serve as a wrapper for all the different types you're going to need). Note that you will have to create use templates to make the map accept different types.